# Recreate devise users table from excel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, devise

I want to have my database tables in excel as a backup so I am able to reseed my database from scratch.

So far everything works OK, except the devise users model.

The code looks like this:

```
*users.rb*

  def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)
    header = spreadsheet.sheet(0).row(1)    #sheet(0) is the first sheet

    (2..spreadsheet.sheet(0).last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.sheet(0).row(i)].transpose]
      user = find_by(fullname: row["Fullname"]) || new

      user.update_fields(row) 

    end
  end

  def update_fields(fields)
    self.fullname = fields["Fullname"]
    self.email = fields["Εmail"]
    self.role = fields["Role"]
    self.encrypted_password = fields["Enc. Password"]
    self.reset_password_token = fields["Password Token"]
    self.confirmed_at = fields["Confirm. Date"]
    self.confirmation_sent_at = fields["Confirm. SentAt"]
    self.confirmation_token = fields["Confirm. Token"]

    self.save!
  end
```

When the save is executed I get a rollback error that the Password cannot be blank. I am confused because no password seems to be kept in the database. What it seems to be saved is an encrypted password which *I am* importing from excel (so it is not blank).

Any ideas?

Comment: So the database encrypts the password.  That value cannot be put into another table just as is.  You would have to decrypt them, store them unencyrpted passwords on the sheet, and then use the unencyrpted passwords in that file when re seeding the db.

Comment: Why not just back up the db with a dump file or something that would work as import/export, as opposed to storing everyone's unencyrpted passwords? What is the database?

Comment: You can skip the password validation by using `self.save(validate: false)`, but, as Rockwell commented, it would just be easier to use a dumpfile to restore your database.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a little bit on the dump file solution?

Comment: Also, if what you want is being able to easily reseed your development database, that's what the `db/seeds.rb` file is for.

Comment: Actually, it is the production database that I have in mind :)

Comment: @kouroubel so you can import and export data from your database pretty easily depending on the database.  This, for example, would explain how to do that with a postgresql db on Heroku.  There would be steps for whatever db you are using online somewhere I am sure. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Comment: A big thank you to both. The self.save(validate: false) suggestion worked like a charm and the Heroku documentation seems like a very interesting alternative (yes, I am deploying on Heroku)...

Comment: No problem! But yeah, you should really use a dump file, that's exactly what they are for! And heroku makes it really easy to download/restore your backups :)